# Where did Kuhn draw a parallel with Quine's thesis of the indeterminacy of translation?

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-science, history-of-philosophy, philosophy-of-language, kuhn

About Thomas S. Kuhn, In the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy I read:

> Early on Kuhn drew a parallel with Quine's thesis of the indeterminacy of translation (1970a, 202; 1970c, 268)

Which is the Kuhn's original source

> (1970)

this is referred to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See T.Kuhn, “Reflections on my Critics”, in [Criticism and the Growth of Knowledge](https://books.google.it/books?id=Vutfm5n6LKYC&pg=PA268), Imre Lakatos and Alan Musgrave (editors), Cambridge University Press (1970).

See page 268, with ref to Quine (1960) : *Word and Object*.

And see also T.Kuhn, [*SSR* (1962, 2nd ed. 1970)](https://books.google.it/books?id=3eP5Y_OOuzwC&printsec=frontcover) :

- *Preface*, page viii: "W.V.O. Quine opened for me the philosophical
  puzzles of the analytic-synthetic distinction [ref. to "Two Dogmas of Empiricism," reprinted in *From a Logical Point of View* (Cambridge, Mass., 1953)]";
- *Postscript* (1969), page 202: "The already classic source for most of the relevant aspects of translation is W.V.O. Quine, *Word and Object* (Cambridge, Mass., 1960)".

The ref T.Kuhn (1970a) that is missing into SEP's entry *Bibliography*, is the second edition (1970) of *SSR*.

Comment: This book is a very good summary of all sides of this particular argument, if you can still find it.