# Kuhn's essay "Reflections on my critics" is named [1970b] or [1970c]?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, kuhn

About Thomas Kuhn's essay *Reflections on my Critics* I found two different refereces:

In The Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy it's reported as [1970c], see:

> 1970c, “Reflections on my Critics”, in Criticism and the Growth of Knowledge, I. Lakatos and A. Musgrave (eds.), London: Cambridge University Press: 231–78.

In a collection of Kuhn's essays (*Dogma contro critica - Mondi possibili nella storia della scienza*) I see that a quote from the above-mentioned essay is associated to Kuhn [1970b] instead than [1970c] (footnote134, p.335). 
On the other hand, on The Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy the [1970b] is associated to a different essay (*Logic of Discovery or Psychology of Research?*), see the following:

> 1970b, “Logic of Discovery or Psychology of Research?”, in Criticism and the Growth of Knowledge, edited by I. Lakatos and A. Musgrave, London: Cambridge University Press: 1–23.

I wonder whether one of the sources is incorrect (in particular, should I trust The Stanford Encyclopedia if Philosophy?) or if letters [1970a, 1970b, 1970c and so on] may change, as the case may be.

In any case, which of them (1970c and 1970b) is more appropriate to use, by referring to the Kuhn's *Reflections on my Critics*?

Comment: Sorry, but this kind of question has nothing to do with phil... In teh SEP's entry  the author use a Biblio: in it, the author has listed (because he needed so) three 1970 Kuhn's papers ([we already discusses the fact that - presumably by a typo - 1970a is missing](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/53602/where-did-kuhn-draw-a-parallel-with-quines-thesis-of-the-indeterminacy-of-trans)) : named 1979a,b and c. Why do you expect that a different book with a different Biblio lists the same papers with the same "codes".

Comment: Basically, you're just asking how citations work in modern publications in English... answer: in one system, each publication by the same author in the same year gets a letter after the year which applies *only* to that article and helps you know which Kuhn 1979 article it means...

Comment: One of them probably decided the a, b, c alphabetically (by the name of the paper) and one of them probably did it by which was referenced first in the main text. Either way, it doesn't matter. The letters are only there to let you know when you're reading the main text which source they mean, different authors may do it differently and that's why you look at the specific bibliography in the text you're currently using. This isn't a question about philosophy, as pointed out above, maybe you should try asking it on academia.SE?

Comment: Thank you for replying and sorry for the off topic. I voted to close the question (or should I delete it?)